# Is it possible to pass data from laravel controller then to component vue?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am new to vue can I ask how to pass data variable from my controller to vue component

here is my controller

```
$categories = Category::all();

return  view('dashboard.index',compact('categories');
```

in my dashboard.index I want to grab that variable to my vue component, but I have no idea how.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard.index, add your vue component and pass categories as props.

It should look like this.

`<your-component-name :category="{{ $categories }}">`

and inside your component you should have like this one.

props: {
   category: Array/String/Boolean (depends on what type of data is categories)
}